# Почему сортировка Питон, сортирует неправильно? В чём ошибка сортировки?

Tags: python, сортировка

```
def selection_sort(must):
    print('selection sort')
    for i in range(0, len(must) - 1):
        smallest = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(must)):
            if must[j] < must[smallest]:
                smallest = j
        must[i], must[smallest] = must[smallest], must[i]

must1 = input('Введите путь к файлу: ')
with open(must1) as file:
    must = [row.strip() for row in file]
selection_sort(must)
print(must)
```

В файле разные числа, но выводит это:

```
[265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 27, 270]
```

Тут есть некоторая логика, программа считает, что после `269` идёт `27`, но это не так.
Вот почему она не правильно сортирует? Как сделать так, чтобы все числа по порядку шли?

Comment: Потому что у вас в списке не числа, а строки, а строки сортируются в лексикографическом порядке (алфавитно-цифровом). Это не "неправильно", это другой способ сортировки.

Comment: наверняка же выводит не это, а числа в кавычках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что с файла Вы читаете строки. Именно поэтому "27">"269". Что делать? читать как числа

Но может просто преобразовать к числу? Где то так

```
must = [int(row.strip()) for row in file]
```

Comment: Выводит ошибку ValueError, из-за инт

Comment: @YrecPodlec Покажите полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Возникло исключение: ValueError
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
  File "C:\Users\verbY\Desktop\ISU\Codes Modes\sortiroFka_Viborom.py", line 12, in <listcomp>
    must = [int(row.strip()) for row in file]
  File "C:\Users\verbY\Desktop\ISU\Codes Modes\sortiroFka_Viborom.py", line 12, in <module>
    must = [int(row.strip()) for row in file]

Comment: @YrecPodlec, `ValueError invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` - значит у вас в список пустая строка попадает. Нужно исключить ее из списка, например так: `must = [int(row.strip()) for row in file if row.strip()]`